# Google Analytics not tracking a Wordpress directory

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

Just wondered if there is a known issue with GA having trouble tracking a site which has a Wordpress directory?

It seems to be able to track all of my other pages on the site, but we have a /news/ directory which is powered by Wordpress and it doesn't pick this up at all. It is obviously an issue with the fact that this directory is a Wordpress blog, but there must be a way to track it with all of the other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaahhh... Sounds like the google analytics tracking code is present on your main site pages, but is not included in the wordpress template that's applied to that sub-section of your site.

The GA tracking code must be visible to google on **every** page you want to have tracked.

Try 'View Source' in your browser, and check wether the analytics tracking code is present.

If not, you could hard-code the GA tracking code in, or use one of the free WordPress Plugins to do it for you, like 'Google Analytics':

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/googleanalytics/

Hope this helps - post back if you're still having problems!

Rick

Comment: Ah silly me, completely forgot that the framework I put my GA tracking code into wouldn't affect my Wordpress site. I need to either install one of those plugins or hardcode it in.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be related, but did you check if your blog is indexable? Under Settings -> Privacy you can check if its enabled.

Another option is to install a google analytics plugin for the blog. If you enter the same credentials from your already-in-use GA it should be combined. I'm using this [one](http://yoast.com/wordpress/google-analytics/#utm_source=wordpress&utm_medium=plugin&utm_campaign=wpgaplugin&utm_content=v420) on my blog and its working.